# Difference between two inequality symbols

Tags: inequality, notation

I have come across the symbol $ \leqq$ in a paper I am reading. Is there any difference between this symbol and the symbol $ \leq $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are the same. You should consider them the same symbol in different 'fonts' rather than two different symbols.

Answer (score -1):

Y ≦ X

Means Y is than or equal to every value of X for each correspending component in vector inequality.

Difference is that ≤ is used in calculus and ≦ in vector analysis.

Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols

Comment: I disagree. It certainly isn't a widespread convention to give different meanings to those two symbols. I don't think it would be a good idea either. I would probably not even notice the difference if my guard wasn't up.

Comment: It isn't widespread that's for certain. But that doesn't mean the two symbols can have a different meaning. That is what OP asked.